# Magento admin: Sales / Tax menu disappeared

Tags: admin, xml

Tax settings from the Sales menu have disappeared. It appears this is a conflict with a certain module, when I disable this module from `app/etc/modules` the tax menu reappears.

No menu items from the module are visible.

However, I have not been able to find out the root cause for the problem. All module XML-files seem to be in order. This module and taxes were working before and no changes to the XML-files have been made.

Also I have a local test env, where the module is working. Code is an exact copy in both locations.

I have checked the Magento roles and permissions, everything OK there.

What could possibly cause this behaviour? Could it be some configuration or other setting. If so, what?

Answer (score 0):

> No menu items from the module are visible.

Possibly you disabled module output for this module in "System > Configuration > Advanced" and this module rewrites blocks from `Mage_Tax`, without overriding `getModuleName()` (an often overlooked detail). Now these blocks belong to the module and will be hidden according to the configuration.

Answer (score -1):

go to system-> tools and recompile and run compliation ,hope

Comment: Compilation not in use.

Comment: Need to see code for debug.